# Cors iframe example

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I've been looking for a way to show external sites on an iframe in my https site.

Cors pops up over and over in my searches but I don't see any examples of exactly how to get the page into the iframe.

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://bar.other/resources/public-data/';

   function callOtherDomain() {
   if(invocation) {    
   invocation.open('GET', url, true);
   invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
   invocation.send(); 
           }
      }
```

So now that I have this code, how do I set the src for the iframe

```
    <iframe src="https://otherDomain.com?id="></iframe>
```

I've tried onLoad CallOtheDomain(); and some other tries but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the `src` of the iframe instead of trying to use ajax?

Comment: Why do you need CORS here?  What are you trying to do?  Why not just set the `src` of the iframe to the URL?  Are you trying to talk to the external site?

Comment: it's cross domain, my site is https...

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with CORS. If you want to give a URL to another domain, then you can't use a URL that is relative to the current document.

```
src="http://otherDomain.com?id="
```

Having mixed levels of security in a page is not a good idea though. Since your page is HTTPS, you should load the content of the frame through HTTPS too.

```
src="https://otherDomain.com?id="
```

This, obviously, depends on the other site providing an HTTPS version.

Comment: the other site is not https

Comment: Then it might be blocked by some browsers as you are attempting to load insecure content into a secure page.

Comment: that's what cors allows you to do. Allow cross domain scripting

Comment: You aren't trying to do scripting. You are trying to display content in an iframe.